Creating a csv file from existing Excel sheet renaming active sheet as well
The below works. It creates the csv file just like it should.  For some reason it also renames the original sheet and the workbook.  I have to close the workbook, don't save it, and reopen it again.  I don't want to have to do that every time.  Is there a way around this? I have a lot of these files to create.
Sub CopySheetandSaveasCSV()
    Dim sourceWs As Worksheet
    Dim csvPath As String
    Dim Fname As String
    
    Fname = Range("C2").Value
     csvPath = "C:\Users\(The path is correct here, just dont want to share it) Fname & ".csv"
     
      
    Set sourceWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
  
    sourceWs.SaveAs Filename:=csvPath, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False

End Sub

I was expecting the original workbook and wroksheet to keep its name. I know I still need to turn off the application warnings.

.Copy the sheet first, as demonstrated in the linked thread.
